# Flaky tests query

Tags: postgresql, automated-tests

Given a (postgresql) table of test results, we would like to find tests that are flaky: Tests that fail and then pass on the same run :

```
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------+
| result_id | run_id |    scenario     |            time            |  result  |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------+
|     12031 |    123 | @loginHappyFlow | 2020-12-22 12:23:20.077636 |  Pass    |
|     12032 |    123 | @signUpSocial   | 2020-12-22 12:22:03.355052 |  Fail    |
|     12033 |    123 | @signUpSocial   | 2020-12-22 12:19:19.812301 |  Pass    |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------+
```

Not sure how to approach this, please advice, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.result_id
  ,a.run_id
  ,a.scenario
  ,a.time
  ,a.result
  ,b.quantity
FROM
  table a
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      run_id
      ,scenario
      ,COUNT(*) AS quantity
    FROM
      table
    GROUP BY 1,2
  ) b on (a.run_id = b.run_id and a.scenario = b.scenario)
WHERE
  b.quantity > 1
```